# Are there any nice properties we can talk about after using PCA to transform data to a new basis?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm not talking about "compressing" data here....assume we kept all the eigenvector basis after performing PCA, and then used them to transform our data into a new basis of the same dimension as the original.  Are there any interesting properties between the points that might hold or not hold or change/stay the same?  E.g., are the relative distances between points the same (but just scaled)?

Comment: I don't know much about PCA, but what I know is that it's conencted with the SVD of a matrix $A$ and thus with the spectral decomposition of $A^TA$. So, if you mean the eigenvectors of $A^TA$, when you transform to a new basis, do you mean an orthonormal basis? If yes, this can only be done using an orthogonal (unitary) matrix. And such a transformation preserves distances.

Comment: @amsmath OK cool -- to recap my understanding....if I perform SVD to find $A = UDU^{\dagger}$ and then multiply my data by the orthonormal unitary matrix "U" to obtain a new vector space of the same dimension then Euclidean distances between points is preserved.